# Configurar XAMPP red LAN

Tags: servidor, xampp

Tengo 2 computadores bajo la misma red LAN, en ambos tengo instalado XAMPP, pero quiero tener en uno montado el sitio, y en el otro PC la BBDD. En el archivo de conexión php cambié "localhost" por la ip local del otro pc, pero no me funciona.

Al cargar la página obtengo este error :

> mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No se puede establecer una conexi�n ya
>   que el equipo de destino deneg� expresamente dicha conexi�n.

Cualquier otro dato, estaré atento a los comentarios.

```
Datos del pc con el sitio : 192.168.0.3
Datos del pc con la BBDD : 192.168.0.23
```

Mi conexión PHP:

```
private $server = "192.168.0.23";
private $usr = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $db = "abm";
```

Archivo configuración MySQL del PC con la BBDD (192.168.0.23):

```
# Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients [client] 
# password       = your_password  port            = 3306  socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
datadir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file = "mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solución al mensaje de "conexión rechazada"**

Debes cambiar la siguiente línea del archivo de configuración del servidor MySQL (`my.cnf`):

```
#bind-address="127.0.0.1"
bind-address="0.0.0.0"
```

Con eso permitirás el acceso desde máquinas diferentes a "localhost" (el equipo local).

Tras ese cambio deberás reiniciar el servidor MySQL y ya no recibirás el mensaje de conexión rechazada porque ahora el servidor MySQL está escuchando en todas las interfaces, no sólo la local.

**Solución al problema de "acceso denegado"**

Otro tema son los permisos que te podrían generar un mensaje:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.23' (using password: YES)

Generalmente todos los permisos se generan por defecto para acceder desde "localhost", por lo que deberás agregar permisos nuevos para IPs externas con:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON abm.*
TO 'root'@'%'
IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña_de_acceso';
```

O si quieres que sea únicamente a la IP de tu servidor web:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON abm.*
TO 'root'@'192.168.0.23'
IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña_de_acceso';
```

Tras eso el usuario `root` tendrá acceso remoto a esa base de datos.

**Buena práctica de seguridad**

No te recomiendo el uso del usuario `root` para acceder a datos de una aplicación, deberías crear un usuario específico para cada aplicación y otorgarle permisos mínimos en general y totales a su base de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON abm.* TO 'usuario'@'%';
```

Comment: Hola, intenté eso, pero no me funcionó. Ya puse la respuesta, encontré el error. Gracias igual.

Comment: Creo que deberías analizar bien tu respuesta porque no tiene sentido. Si el problema fuera por permisos el mensaje de error hubiera sido completamente diferente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné. Dejo por acá por si a alguien le sirve.

- Primero se debe crear un usuario en la BBDD al pc a conectarse y darle todos
  los privilegios.

> ```
> Nombre de usuario : user 
> Nombre del host : la ip local donde está alojado el sitio, en mi caso es 192.168.0.3
> Contraseña : *****
> ```

Luego en la conexión del archivo php poner los datos que corresponden

```
private $server = "192.168.0.23";//la ip del PC con la BBDD
private $usr = "user";
private $pass = "****";
```

-

Comment: Siento decirte que esa no es una solución al problema que planteas, aunque sí es uno que te aparece más adelante si no gestionas correctamente los permisos. Probablemente durante un proceso de cambios y pruebas para solucionar tu problema llegaste a esa última opción, pero la solución exacta al mensaje que planteas es la que explico en mi respuesta.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Muchas gracias, voy a seguir los pasos que dejaste en la otra respuesta y te cuento cómo me fue. Saludos.

Comment: De nada @LuisPavez. Si llegaste a este punto significa que solucionaste tu problema. Imagino que primero arreglaste el tema de la conexión rechazada, luego te salió el problema de los permisos y por último arreglaste ese tema usando alguna herramienta externa (phpmyadmin u otro gestor gráfico) que creara el SQL necesario para crear los permisos por ti. Lo importante es que solucionaste tu problema y ya estás funcionando con el servidor web y base de datos separados. Enhorabuena.